# Shopify, nodejs :check shopify api request in app valid or not if scope changed

Tags: node.js, shopify

Can anybody help me about how can i check shopify request valid or not if scope changed, i am creating shopify app in nodejs

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will need to provide us with more information about your current issue and what have you tried. The community tries to help developers with their code problems, not to write the code for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i got my solution,

You could check the status code of your response in node. I think '403 Forbidden' is the one you need. If you are trying to make an api call to a scope you didn't request in the initial oAuth process, a 403 response will be returned and a message like this:

```
{
  errors: "[API] This action requires merchant approval for read_orders scope."
}
```

You can see all the response status codes [here](http://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/response-status-codes)